# How do I transform 2 anchor points at the same time in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Recently, I've seen a video where the guy makes a pyramid by selecting both upper anchor points of a square, and then clicking and dragging with some tool, converging both points to the center. How do I do that? Is it a CC specific tool?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can transform selected anchor points using the **Free Transform Tool**. You do not *have* to transform an entire shape.

I've seen the video. However, I don't recall the *exact* part you are posting about and I'm not going to scour the video for that half second clip. But, with the Free Transform tool you can make a *perspective* transform which will bring two points together.

[image]

You can either select the two anchor points and just move them inward or you can use the perspective transform item on the Free Transform HUD (there's also a somewhat complicated modifier key combo you can use). Either way provides the same alteration.

If you disable the Bounding Box (`View > Hide Bounding Box`) and force yourself to use the Free Transform Tool instead, you'll find *many* more things you can do which the Bounding Box can't. Unfortunately, I think the Bounding Box itself causes users to not explore other tools. The *only* unique thing the Bounding Box does is easily resize area text boxes, beyond that the Bounding Box is honestly not needed.

Comment: Now that, is an awesome answer! Thank you very much sir. Not only did this solve my problem, but also these are great tips.

Answer (score 1):

In the video, he uses the scale tool (s). Select the two points with your direct selection tool, click scale, and then pull into the middle.

Comment: Its this video here http://vimeo.com/113751583 ... there is a moment when he picks one of the black squares and rearrange them proportionally manipulating the anchor points...i'll try to find the moment in the video.